# Display best selling items and associated image from another table

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I would like to display the image of 4 best selling items on the index page but the sql I'm using does not work. I think the syntax is correct but doesn't show anything on the page. I have an *order_items table* and *products table*.

**Products table**

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;
```

**Order_items table**

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=68 ;
```

**NOTE**: in order_items table the field product corresponds to the ID of the product.

Finally, this is the sql statement I'm using but doesn't show anything.

```
   public function bestSellingItems(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products AS p 
   INNER JOIN order_items AS od ON p.id = od.id 
   GROUP BY p.id, SELECT SUM(od.qty) AS total
   ORDER BY SUM(od.qty) DESC limit 4";
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it your self, `product` correspond to `id` and you used `p.id = od.id`  , also, I didn't understand the part of the second select which I believe should throw an error(no from..) so I adjusted it a little bit - select the sum, alias it and order by that alias.

```
   public function bestSellingItems(){
    $sql = "SELECT p.*,od.*,sum(od.qty) as sum_qty FROM products AS p 
   INNER JOIN order_items AS od ON p.id = od.product 
   GROUP BY p.id
   ORDER BY sum_qty DESC limit 4";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your join "INNER JOIN order_items AS od ON p.id = **od.id** " should be INNER JOIN order_items AS od ON p.id = **od.Product**

Comment: And thats the only problem ?